# Why do I have to publish my app to google play before I can test it?

Tags: android, deployment

I'm developing an app that I've uploaded to the ALPHA TESTING tab of the console.

But from what I am reading I have to publish it live in order to allow users from a private community to download and test the app?

This defeats the purpose of ALPHA testing. I have to publish my app live to test an ALPHA version. This ALPHA version is not ready for production hence why it's in ALPHA

If this is not the case, how can I install the APK that I've uploaded to the console in the ALPHA testing tab and give access to a group of users?

I don't see a link to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en?

Only the users from your Google Group will see your app in a Play Market during this testing.

Comment: i would like to know if i have to upload my app in every test (open and internal testing) phase before it can be made public to general.